# list of cities per country and their location info

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, core-location

I am implementing an iPhone application that need the user to choose a city and to get its location (altitude, longitude). Is there any API to list countries/cities with their locations?

Answer (score 2):

You might find what you need here: http://www.geonames.org/